# MVC5 using ajax to pass text data to controller

Tags: ajax, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I'm a total scrub in the process of improving my mvc app site and implement better design. One thing I'm still unable to get working is passing 2 strings to my home controller from the view on a div click.
  I am able to do it very well using Html.BeginForm method with text boxes, but that is not the desired implementation.

view:

```
<a href="#" id=" next">
   <div class="next">
   </div>
</a>

@section scripts
        {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#next").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $ajax({
                type: "Post",
                datatype: "text",
                url: "/Home/Komic",
                data: {
                    action: "next",
                    num: "1"
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
     }
```

controller:

```
   public ActionResult Komics(string action, string num)
    {
        //do stuff
        //will return element in list depending on action/num passed from view
        return View(list.ElementAt(KomicIndex));
     }
```

I've kept it simple for the sake of the post. But the idea is that once the "next" div is clicked, the ajax call will pass the "action" and "num" string parameters to the controller, who will return its view with the determined element from its list.

As mentioned before I can do this easily with this approach:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Komics", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("action")
    @Html.TextBox("num")
    <input type="submit" class="btn" />
}
```

But I **cannot** use it in my design. So I basically want to replicate this same result using ajax and clicking the "next" div.

I've been hammering at this for days; but no dice so far. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to handle the `success` callback and add the partial view you method returns - `success: function(data) { $('.next').html(data); }`

Comment: Thank you, will try that asap and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var info={"action":"text",
          "num":"1"};
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("Komics","Home")',
            data: info,
            error:function(error){
              //do sth
          },
            success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
            //see the result comes from server
          }
        });
```